# Put raw string into the regex

Tags: python, html, regex, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use a regex to find a tag with `BeautifulSoup`.

The problem is that I don't know all special characters representing `regex` symbols, so I don't know where to put `/`.

Let's say that there is this text in one `div` tag:  **`v katalógu rôznych firiem`** and the web page has charset - **`utf-8`**

`result = soup.find('div',text=re.compile('.*'+r'v katalógu rôznych firiem'+'.*'))`

If I try to `print` a `result` I get `None` type but I'm sure that there is a tag like this.

What could be wrong? Is there a problem with `regex` or `encoding`?

Here is the example:

```
<div class="col-sm-10"><h1 class="word-ma">Selsso</h1> —                <b>Zobrazený 1</b> výsledok nájdený                v katalógu rôznych firiem        </div>
```

Comment: Show the exact tag you are trying to parse.

Comment: I've attached it there. Thanks

Comment: The text `katalógu rôznych firiem` is not present in the example.

Comment: Sorry I've added another example. It is all right now. But the tag has to be found by the text, not by class name or something else. Do you now how to do that? I could iterate over all divs but it is too time expensive and the second thing is that I want to solve it this way.

Comment: I put the regex and the new example into Pythex and it found it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I work in Pycharm and it could not find it. So I can provide you real example: http://www.zoznam.sk/hladaj.fcgi?co=odkazy&s=kovac  Can you find the div which contains "v katalógu Zoznam" ? I've already tried even this '.*'+r'Zoznam'+'.*' but no success....

Comment: This really is a XY question...@Milan: Did you tried `soup.find('div', text=re.compile('.*'))`? Also you could try `soup.find(text=re.compile('.*'))` and `re.search('.*'+r'v katalógu rôznych firiem'+'.*', soup.text).group()`.

Comment: Yes I've tried it. It returns 1 result even when I try find_all... weird

Comment: So `soup.find('div', text=re.compile('.*'))` can only find `Selsso` in your example. What does your code can do...

Comment: @Milan could you please post all the elements HTML code you want to locate by text? Thanks.